# Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid. EF6, Navigation Property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I was trying to solve a many to many relation. On a database level everthing looks good to me, but when I tryr to get that data(`inlcude`), it fails.

I get:

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.

What I call/tried:

```
var readRecipes = db.MyClasses. 
                     Include(blog => blog.SomeCollections).ThenInclude(post => post.Prop1).
                     Include(blog => blog.SomeCollections).ThenInclude(post => post.Prop2).
```

**Structure**

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass{
// ...                   
public ICollection<NavigationProperty> NavigationPropertys; 
// ...               
public MainClass()
{

    this.NavigationPropertys = new Collection<NavigationProperty>(); 
}
}
```

NavigationProperty:

```
public class NavigationProperty
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }



        [Required]
        public Guid? Prop1ID { get; set; }// 0,*

        [Required]
        public Guid? Prop2ID { get; set; }// 0,*

        [Required]
        public Guid MainClassID { get; set; }



        [Required]
        public Prop1 Prop1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Prop2 Prop2 { get; set; }




        public MainClass MainClass { get; set; }



        [Required]
        public float Amount { get; set; }


        public NavigationProperty()
        {
            // todo: ?
        }
    }
```

I don't know, what I did wrong ?

Comment: Uhm, so `Recipes` = `MainClass` and `SomeCollection` = `NavigationProperty` ? You could improve your post by just including the necessary properties. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: @Dennis1679 you are right, I corrected it. Should I include `Prop1` and `Prop2` as well ?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I solved my question.

Instead of:

```
public ICollection<NavigationProperty> NavigationPropertys;
```

I should have used:

```
public ICollection<NavigationProperty> NavigationPropertys { get; set; };
```

This made Lambda crash.

Thank You.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to include the children of a navigational property as well you should do:

```
Parent.Include(p => p.Children.Select(c => c.GrandChild));
```

or if there are many grand children per child

```
Parent.Include(p => p.Children.SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren));
```

or if there is only one child and one grand child per parent.

```
Parent.Include(p => p.Child.GrandChild);
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
I didn't realise that your question was regarding ef-core. I thought it was some type of pseudo code or self made extension method.

Have you read through [all the examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) provided by Microsoft regarding this topic? Otherwise I'm afraid that I don't have enough info to assist you in the matter.

One thing that I'll need to see is how you configured the relationship between `Prop1` and the Navigation entity. I don't see a foreign key in your model. Of course this is not necessary depending on how you configured the relationship in the overridden `OnModelCreating` method using the `modelBuilder` in your `DbContext` or how you used the attributes to indicate the relationship. More about relationships and specifying relationships in ef-core can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: Your example blatantly skips the use of `.ThenInclude`, something that is specifically designed for including multiple levels of inheritance. It might work, but you're providing no reason why he should favor `SelectMany` over `ThenInclude`,

Comment: You are right. But the OP specifically states: Lambda expression used inside **Include** is not valid. But you are right in his tags he has indirectly stated that he is asking about ef-core. I will see if I can revise my answer. Thanks